# Codeigniter Load more content button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am current creating an online examination system. I wanted to add a *load more* functionality so that the examiners will not be overwhelmed with a lot of questions on page load. I got my codes from different sources and tried to combine them based on what I know.

Everything works great **BUT** the problem is I used html tags in my controller which I think is not right?? based on what MVC concept is concern. I tried to directly put the html codes in my views page but I get looping issue :(. Here is my code.

**MODEL**

```
    public function getQuestion1($page, $id){
    $offset = 10*$page;
    $limit = 10;
    $sql = "select * from question_bank where examtype_id = $id limit $offset ,$limit";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
    return $result;
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public function verbal(){
    $this->load->view('examination/includes/header');
    $this->load->view('examination/verbal_meaning');
    $this->load->view('examination/includes/footer');
}


public function getQuestion(){
    $page =  $this->input->get('page');
    $questions = $this->examination_model->getQuestion1($page,1);
    foreach($questions as $r) {
        echo "<div class='col-lg-6'>
        <br/>
        <label>"
        .$r->question_id.") ".$r->question.
        "</label>
        <div class='radio'>
        <ol type='1'>
        <div class='col-lg-6'>
        <li>
        <label>
        <input type='radio' name='verbal_q5' id='' value='1'>"
        .$r->option1.
        "</label>
        </li>
        <li>
        <label>
        <input type='radio' name='verbal_q5' id='' value='2'>"
        .$r->option2.
        "</label>
        </li>
        <li>
        <label>
        <input type='radio' name='verbal_q5' id='' value='2'>"
        .$r->option2.
        "</label>
        </li>
        </div>
        <div class='col-lg-6'>
        <li>
        <label>
        <input type='radio' name='verbal_q5' id='' value='3'>"
        .$r->option4.
        "</label>
        </li>
        <li>
        <label>
        <input type='radio' name='verbal_q5' id='' value='4'>"
        .$r->option5.
        "</label>
        </li>
        </div>
        </ol>
        </div>
        </div>";
    }
    exit;
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="ajax_table">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    getquestion(0);
    $("#load_more").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var page = $(this).data('val');
      getquestion(page);
    });
  });
  var getquestion = function(page){

    $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>examination/getQuestion",
      type:'GET',
      data: {page:page}
    }).done(function(response){
      $("#ajax_table").append(response);
      $('#load_more').data('val', ($('#load_more').data('val')+1));
      scroll();
    });
  };
  var scroll  = function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#load_more').offset().top
    }, 1000);
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should to is:

Create one php veriable with all tags using loop rather than directly echo the content to ajax. And then send the variable as a response to ajax and then append the html content to view within the element `ajax_table`.

This would be the best and proper way.

Comment: Im new to codeigniter framework. Do you have any examples about what you are talking about? But I will try your suggestion. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think most Codeigniter developers will agree that html belongs in a view file.

Based on your comment, "but I get looping issue" I suspect that you are not passing values to the view file correctly. It should be done like this.

```
public function getQuestion()
{
    $page =  $this->input->get('page');
    $data['questions'] = $this->examination_model->getQuestion1($page,1);
    $this->load->view('examination/question_view', $data);
}
```

Note that the model return is assigned to the array `$data` with an item key of 'questions'.

```
$data['questions'] = $this->examination_model->getQuestion1($page,1);
```

The item key becomes a variable in the view. In other words, `$data['questions']` becomes the variable `$questions` in the view. Note that `$data` is passed to the view in the second argument of `load->view`.

```
$this->load->view('examination/question_view', $data);
```

The file "*examination/question_view.php*" will contain both PHP and HTML and use the same technique you show in the controller above.

Your HTML will cause you problems as you load additional questions. The main problem is that, based on what you show, all the `<input type=radio` fields have the same name. Radio buttons are "grouped" by providing the same name attribute to each related button.  As you have it, as you add more questions to the page all the buttons will be in the same group because ALL of them have the same name. Oops.

Below I provide HTML that should solve that problem and keep each question's answers in unique button groups. I've also used a more traditional way of structuring the inputs and labels.

Additionally, I've removed some of your HTML related to layout and formatting just to keep the code more readable. Once you get the logic working you can add HTML elements and CSS classes as needed to create the layout you have in mind.

Here is my version of "*examination/question_view.php*"

```
<?php
foreach($questions as $question) :
    $q_num = $question->question_id;
    $q_id = "q".$q_num;
    $name = "verbal_".$q_num;
    ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= "Question $q_num"; ?></legend>
        <div>
            <?= $question->question; ?>
        </div>
        <ol type='1'>
            <li>
                <?php $id = "{$q_id}_a1"; ?>
                <input type='radio' name='<?= $name; ?>' id='<?= $id; ?>' value='1'>
                <label for='<?= $id; ?>'><?= $question->option1; ?></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <?php $id = "{$q_id}_a2"; ?>
                <input type='radio' name='<?= $name; ?>' id='<?= $id; ?>' value='2'>
                <label for='<?= $id; ?>'><?= $question->option2; ?></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <?php $id = "{$q_id}_a3"; ?>
                <input type='radio' name='<?= $name; ?>' id='<?= $id; ?>' value='3'>
                <label for='<?= $id; ?>'><?= $question->option2; ?></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <?php $id = "{$q_id}_a4"; ?>
                <input type='radio' name='<?= $name; ?>' id='<?= $id; ?>' value='4'>
                <label for='<?= $id; ?>'><?= $question->option4; ?></label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <?php $id = "{$q_id}_a5"; ?>
                <input type='radio' name='<?= $name; ?>' id='<?= $id; ?>' value='5'>
                <label for='<?= $id; ?>'><?= $question->option5; ?></label>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
endforeach;
```

I did not actually test this markup so it might not be perfect. Please forgive any typos or logic problems.

If you are not familiar with the PHP alternate syntax I have used - e.g. `<?= $name; ?>` - that is the same a typing `<?php echo $name; ?>`.

You probably also notice how I drop in and out of the PHP processor by setting some areas off inside `<?php ...code here... ?>` and then type HTML instead of echoing strings to PHP. There is no performance penalty for doing this. It is also a lot easier to type and to read. (IMO)

I also have a tendency to evaluate variables within a double-quote string. e.g.

```
<?= "Question $q_num"; ?>
```

instead of of concatenating them using a dot, e.g.

```
<?= "Question ".$q_num; ?>
```

The results are the same and, for me, the first is easier to type and to read.

Also notice the use of curly braces in some of those double-quote strings. e.g.

```
<?php $id = "{$q_id}_a1"; ?>
```

The "curlies" help the PHP processor figure out what part is a variable and what part is a string literal. The previous example could also be written

```
<?php $id = $q_id."_a1"; ?>
```

BTW, I notice you used `exit;` in the controller. I recommend that you not used `exit` or `die` in Codeigniter except for debugging during the development stage. It is better to let Codeigniter execute its defined shutdown process.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I learned a lot from your response. I will definitely try it out.

Comment: I tried what you suggested me to do, everything works great. The problem is i need to implement a load more functionality that divides the questions in 10s. Which will not work based on your response. But thank you anyways!